# APEX Class To List Multiple Queries To Be Used In VisualForce Page

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

***New to SF development ***
I'm working toward this end goal; Create a custom button on the Opportunity. When that button is pushed, a VisualForce page will display records from 2 custom objects that have a relationship to that Opportunity(ID).  Both custom objects relate to the Opportunity via a custom lookup field.

As a rookie, I'm not sure if I'm starting in the right spot. Here is how I'm trying to in my head. The code below is for items #1 & #2 below.

1. Create a class methods that query the separate data. Each method would be a separate query/list
2. Include coding to pull in a variable of the current Opportunity ID
3. Create VisualForce page that displays queried data
4. Create button that triggers the APEX Code

---

```
public with sharing class TestDisplayQueryList{ 

public Opportunity currRec {get; set;}     
public static List<Opportunity> oppRecords {get; set;} 
public static List<Billing__c> billRecords {get; set;} 
public static List<Service__c> servRecords {get; set;}   

public TestDisplayQueryList(){ 
currRec = [SELECT ID FROM Opportunity WHERE :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];   
oppRecords = [SELECT Name, StageName ID FROM Opportunity WHERE ID= :currRec];
billRecords = [SELECT Name, Invoice ID FROM Billing WHERE Opportunity_Name_c= :currRec];  
servRecords = [SELECT Name, Department ID FROM Service WHERE Opportunity_Name_c= :currRec];     
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

3.) there are a bunch of ways to do this, The simplest is just a pageblock table
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_iteration_components.htm

put your value as your list from your controller, you will need a seperate pageblock table for each list.

4.)
Create a custom button or link, you can do this using salesforce custom button, Just make it a url and pass it the ?id at the end of the url. This will automatically cause the code to run because the code can be ran upon page initialization. you will place this button on the opportunity page.

If you want to show the infromation in a popup window( which will be look and act better for the system) you can also do a custom button, just do a javascript button. there are a ton of tutorials online for making a button for a popup window in javascript. the javascript can extend to the controller and pass the opportunity id as well.

If you get stuck, please let me know and best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you could do this much easier than you think.

VisualForce has an abundance of standard components that can be used for tasks like this.

Below is an example VisualForce page for you:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityExt">

    <!-- Either include all related lists by setting the relatedList attribute to true -->
    <apex:detail subject="{!opportunity.Id}" relatedList="false"/>

    <!-- Or by Including the related lists seperately -->
    <apex:relatedList list="OpportunityLineItems" />
    <apex:relatedList list="OpportunityCompetitors" />

    <!-- To use a button to display a panel, create the panel to reRender after our button action is complete -->
    <apex:outputPanel id="thePanel">

        <!-- Then create the buttons -->
        <apex:commandButton action="{!showThePanel}" value="Show Panel" reRender="thePanel" rendered="{!NOT(showPanel)}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!hideThePanel}" value="Hide Panel" reRender="thePanel" rendered="{!showPanel}"/>

        <!-- And inside that panel create a block that will only render when the flag is set -->
        <!-- Note the use of outputPanel and outputText differently -->
        <!-- OutputText leaves no container behind, outputPanel does so we need it for the "identifying panel" -->
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!showPanel}">

            <!-- You can then include the related lists you wanted -->
            <apex:relatedList list="OpenActivities" />

        </apex:outputText>

    </apex:ouputPanel>

</apex:page>
```

And this would be the extension for that page:

```
public with sharing class OpportunityExt {

    private Opportunity theOpportunity;
    public Boolean showPanel {get; private set;}

    public OpportunityExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        // Get the Opportunity from the standard controller
        theOpportunity = (Opportunity) controller.getRecord();

        // By default don't display the panel - or do, it's your task
        showPanel = false;

    }

    public void showThePanel() {

        showPanel = true;

    }

    public void hideThePanel() {

        showPanel = false;

    }

}
```

For your reference here are the documentation links:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_detail.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm